# How to prove to our users that they are not being cheated?

Tags: privacy, information-theory

I have an information theory question about how to prove (or at least give statistical evidence) that an auction website is not shilling its users.

We recently launched a pay-per-bid auction website. It is a new type of auction where the users pay to bid on timed auctions. Each bid raises the price and increases the time of the auction. The last bidder when the time runs out gets to buy the item.

The problem is that users are suspicious that we may be cheating them. I have no such intentions as the trust of my users is of paramount importance to me. However, the model could be implemented by other unscrupulous sites and it would be straightforward to cheat bidders. I need to put measures in place that will show our users that we are legitimate.

I am committed to running an honest operation. The challenge is how to prove this to the world? Any approach will need to be balanced with preserving the privacy of users.

Some ideas I have are:

- show IP address of each user
- solicit testimonials from winners who
  have received their merchandise. Have
  them mail in photos of them with
  their merchandise and a recent cover
  copy of their local paper.
- show some broad information about each user, such as home state and country

I am looking for any suggestions.

**Update**

Some great suggestions. So far:

- Provide behavioral information about each users:

  - when joined
  - which auctions took part of
  - stats for auction - bids placed, cost
- do not publish personally identifiable information. No IP address, since people who did not win could exact retribution on the winner.
- public forum for discussion and address questions
- solicit testimonials from users to show that people do win and do receive products.

  - how can we show in the testimonial that it is not "invented" by us? I am thinking of perhaps asking to include a photo with a recent local newspaper. This would be hard to fake on a large scale, and how distribution of winners through time and locality.

Do you believe it would be OK to show the home State and Country of user, or would that be too much personal information?

Comment: No, impossible. The very design is a cheat even if you don't explicitly implement a cheating mechanism.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Provide as much information as possible to users, such as who won, how much was paid, how many buys/sellers a user has made, etc;
2. Provide a feedback mechanism on individual auctions and users;
3. Have a public forum for discussion on results, support issues and complaints by users;
4. Don't require users to use other pay services you provide to get results, such as your own snipe system;
5. State your policies clearly on your Website. This should include, at a minimum, a privacy policy, discussion of how the site works, an FAQ and steps you've taken to prevent any appearance of impropriety or conflict of interest (eg employees aren't allowed to participate); and
6. Have a complaints and dispute resolution mechanism.

This isn't a technical problem. It's a social problem. The only way users are going to feel confident in the results is with transparency and professionalism.

Comment: I like your answers. Could open up the discussion in the area of of suggestion 1 - which info would be valuable?

Comment: Show total amount of bids on the item.

Comment: Bids on items, auctions started and won by a particular user, positive/negative feedback count on a user, ideally a link the auctions started/won by that user, join date for site maybe, stats on how much "extra time" auctions have had

Answer (score 4):

Isn't that something like [swoopo.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001196.html)?

Comment: I'm voting this down because it's not an answer, but I see the similarity and it makes me…quite uneasy.

Comment: You are correct, the business model is similar. However, the question is not about the business model itself, but rather at how to prove to users that they are not being cheated.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but the business model of swoopo.com is a cheat in itself however implemented. If yours is the same, my polite suggestion would be to look for other auction types.

Answer (score 3):

It first and foremost must be designed well and look professional enough that people will trust it. People are remarkably good at detecting a poorly designed website and will not respond well to it. 
This may be a hard market to get into since there are such well established alternatives, but the best way to gain users is by word of mouth from existing users. This takes time, but is most effective. 
Don't go violating people's privacy and publishing their information jsut because they use your site. People won't like it and won;t come back.
Provide a feedback system for users (a la ebay) where people can see other real people that are pleased with the service. 
Also a public message board for comments and complaints would help comfort people as well. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Be ware of providing too much information though, depending on your site, your users may decide that they do not like it when too much privacy is revealed to others when they bid on something.  For example, if I'm a customer and I just purchased something expensive, I do not want my user name or email shown to other people who'll start spamming me to buy a cheaper version of what I just paid for.  Some others may take offense at being out bid and grief the person who out bid them by running a DOS on their IP, for example.

Yes you should protect your own site's reputation, but if you do not take actions to protect your users, you may end up losing some of them.

I think the best way to improve your reputation is through usage (may be hard), or through some reputable review sites.

Answer (score 3):

Giving out IP addresses of users might be risky, and ultimately it's something that a fake site may fake as well.

I guess one way of gaining trust is to use a trustworthy authority to approve you. IOW, delegation :) let someone else solve the problem for you. e.g. Users will tend to trust you more if you're backed by someone like PayPal. That would cost you, though.

[philosophical]

The main problem is that in order to gain trust you need to provide what sociologists call "honest signals". And honest signals are usually costly. That's a problem in business because it means you have to sacrifice your earnings in order to get more customers on-board, and then balance that equation. IOW, customers and shareholders have different incentives. But as a "starup" trying to gain the trust of a user base it would make sense to signal your honesty by costly gestures. You might make less money initially, but eventually, once you're big enough, that signalling would no longer be necessary.

So what kind of honest (costly) signal can you send? Well, maybe instead of soliciting testimonials from winners you should Pay them a symbolic fee. Make it worthwhile for users to help you prove the site's authenticity by disclosing information about themselves or the transaction, and in turn make it up for them with discounts, rebates, whatever.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure you won't gain trust by simply handing out people's information to everyone without asking them. Let people do that for you, and compensate them, thereby signalling your intentions in a costly (honest) manner.

[/philosophical]

Comment: Agree with the giving out information. Do you think showing the home State and Country would be OK? If a user agrees in a testimonial, we could also show first name or home town.

Answer (score 2):

Have real time chat on the bidding pages, like IRC. People can only bid by typing "#bid $200" or something in the chat window. That way users can interrogate anyone they think might be a bot or whatever. They can also discuss the product for sale and warn others if it's a fake listing or whatever. You need to show people they can trust the site. People trust people.

Comment: The thought crossed our minds. Some other websites have done this and closed it down because it provides an easy forum for collusion.

Answer (score 2):

You cant without lying.

The only way to win is by sheer luck. You just call your lottery tickets "bids".

Shame on you.

EDIT:
Some opinions on penny auctions
[Profitable Until Deemed Illegal](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001196.html) 
[Penny Auctions: They're Gambling](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001261.html)

Comment: Your answer does not address the question.

Comment: Yes it does. "You cant" is an answer. They (the users) are (in my opinion) being cheated. So any proof would be false.

Answer (score 2):

Remember sitting through a talk on use of cryptographic methods to prove various facets of auctions were conducted properly.  Googling "cryptography" and "auctions" together should provide some starting material if your interested in this approach.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzVCrSrZIX8

http://www.cs.virginia.edu/crab/Auctions.ppt

Comment: Is there a way to present the cyrpto proof in such a way that it would be of value to an average user?

Comment: Yes of course.  In much the same way we don't have to know anything about cryptography, PKI, certificate chains to know if we have a secure connection in our web browsers.  These systems ususally include software programs to provide mortals confidence in the outcome by verifying signatures..etc without leaking propritary information such as amounts of competing bids.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Atwood talked about this on www.codinghorror.com last month.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001261.html

I had never heard of the concept before.  He does explain it fairly well.

Cathy

Answer (score 1):

Open source?

Comment: Then the users would have to trust that a) the source is what's being used, b) there's nothing in addition to the source (like a cron job that inflates bids by trying to buy items)

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of trust and so is a social, not technical issue.

Even if you open-sourced the code and/or had an information theoretical proof, how many of your customers would understand it?

In situations like this, many companies rely on a the word of a trusted third party who has inspected the company's operations. The third party stakes its reputation on its public statement that the company is doing business correctly.